# ksprintf type error when using dynamic string

Tags: f#, printf, unit-type

The sample code:

```ml
Printf.ksprintf ignore "static string"

let dynamicString = Printf.StringFormat<unit>("dynamic string")
Printf.ksprintf ignore dynamicString // <- error
```

When I pass a static string to **ksprintf** everything works fine. But if I form a string dynamically, a compilation error shows up:

> The type 'unit' does not match the type 'string'

P.S. Found in the sources of FSharp.Core:

```ml
/// <summary>Represents a statically-analyzed format when formatting 
/// arguments of the format operation and the last the overall return type.</summary>
type StringFormat<'T,'Result> = Format<'T, unit, string, 'Result>

/// <summary>Represents a statically-analyzed format when formatting builds a string. 
/// The type parameter indicates the arguments and return type of the 
/// format operation.</summary>
type StringFormat<'T> = StringFormat<'T,string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct type for the format string is not `unit`.  It should be

```
let dynamicString = Printf.StringFormat<unit,unit>("dynamic string")
```

To find this out, create a function like this:

```
let test arg = Printf.ksprintf ignore arg
```

and look at the generated type for `arg`